# How to combine magrittr pipes and %in% inside a dplyr::filter predicate function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the **input data frame**

```
library(dplyr)
( df <- data_frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), y = letters[1:6]) )
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#      id     y
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     1     b
# 3     1     c
# 4     2     d
# 5     2     e
# 6     3     f
```

Assume one wants to get a subset of `df[, c("id", "y")]` only with the two most common ids, which are `id` `1` and `2`:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% .$id %>% print -> ids #*
# [1] 1 2
```

**Question: Is there a way to use a pipe in a predicate function inside `filter`** in the veins of:

```
df %>% filter(
  id %in%  df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% .$id  )
# Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "logical"

df %>% filter(
  id %in%  (df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% .$id)  )
# Error: cannot handle

df %>% filter(
  id %in%  {df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% .$id}  )
# Error: cannot handle
```

?

I mean, the last two predicates seem to work as expected outside of `filter`:

```
df$id %in% (df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% .$id)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
df$id %in% {df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% .$id}
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Side note: I know I *could* use a temporary variable `ids`:

```
df %>% filter(id %in% ids) # *ids <- c(1,2)
```

or I could use `*_join`:

```
df %>% inner_join(
  df %>% group_by(id) %>% tally %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(2) %>% select(-n))
```

Both yield the **expected output**:

```
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#      id     y
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     1     b
# 3     1     c
# 4     2     d
# 5     2     e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make this complicated for its own sake.

```
ids <- (df %>% count(id) %>% arrange(n) %>% tail(2))$id
filter(df, id %in% ids)
```

Comment: agree that the OP searchs for overkill with `dplyr` :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it's not different from side note #1 (?). My question is not about selecting the 1st two common ids easily (= this is just an ex.), but about a general possibility to use pipes inside `filter` (or `filter_`?) predicate expressions. Maybe the _question_ is a bit overkill in terms of length and lack of clarity, I could agree, and sry if it's so. :) But pipes - to me, as a non-programmer - offer several advantages over standard notations like better mapping the though process, beeing easier to read & interpret by others etc. Hmm and that's mainly why I asked.

Comment: You _could_ turn that into a one-liner: `filter(df, id %in% (df %>% count_("id") %>% arrange_("n") %>% tail(2))[["id"]])` but any readability gain is completely lost. Just go with the temporary variable.

Comment: And that applies in general, not just this specific case. Pipelines are for readability, not efficiency; if you find that a pipeline is unreadable, you've lost the point of using it.

Comment: Indeed, `df %>% filter(id %in% (df %>% count_("id") %>% arrange_("n") %>% tail(2) %>% .$id) )` - I'll take that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it in magrittr or dplyr, it's not overthinking to wonder how and ask. Once you see it and how ugly it is, fair enough, there are more readable methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to go for continuous chaining but without sticking too much to `dplyr`/`filter` since other solutions exist - still compatible with `%>%`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    tally %>% 
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    head(2) %>% 
    .$id %>% 
    is.element(df$id, .) %>% 
    subset(df, .)

Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

     id     y
  (dbl) (chr)
1     1     a
2     1     b
3     1     c
4     2     d
5     2     e
```

Chaining and then wrapping the chain can be messy when the chain becomes long.

For such a reuslt I would rather go for a base R one liner:

```
df[df$id %in% as.integer(names(tail(sort(table(df$id)),2))),]
```